# Word's Find/Replace Modal in VBA

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2013

I want to prepare and show the Find/Replace dialog. However, the following code shows the dialog in a modal status, and you can't get to the document text.

Any ideas how make it modeless, just like you get from Ctl-H?

```
Public Sub AutoFind()
    On Error GoTo myErrorHandler

    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

    Dim theDialog As dialog
    Set theDialog = Application.Dialogs(wdDialogEditReplace)
    theDialog.Find = "the"
    theDialog.replace = "an"

    theDialog.Show
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like modal is the only behavior by design, but there is a work-around:

`CommandBars.FindControl(ID).Execute`

With the proper ID, this is analogous to hitting the button with your mouse to open the dialog.

I have never used this myself except to confirm it works in v2010, and my instinct says one ought look for a way to confirm or derive the ID number (or perhaps there's a constant one can use) since this is a hard-coded "magic number" that may change from version to version.

In Word 2010, which I have handy, "Find" is ID:=141, "Replace" is ID:=313.

So you can set up a "programmatic" search, and then call use the above CommandBars method to open the dialog. It ought to be populated the way you want it and ought to be non-modal.

```
Sub TestMacro()
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "test find field"
        .Replacement.Text = "test replace field"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With

    CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=313).Execute
end sub
```

Of course, non-modal also means code execution continues immediately.

Answer (score 0):

This was my hacky solution:

```
SendKeys "^h"   ' Hack to obtain "Dialogs(wdDialogEditReplace).Show" modelessly.
' MS Disclaimer: SendKeys is unreliable as to there being no certainty as to where focus is when called.
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is quite old but it was extremely helpful to find a solution for my very similar problem, thus I dare the answer:

In order to make the use of cross-references more accessible to less experienced Word users of my target group, I coded a macro which allows the corresponding dialog box to be called with certain presets, in particular "Numbered item" as reference type and the insertion of the cross reference as a hyperlink.

One reason for this is that after starting Word, the default reference type is "Heading" and the checkbox for "Insert as hyperlink" is deactivated (after that, the last-used settings form the default ones). On the other hand, all our heading styles consist of those for the actual headings (text) and a linked list style for hierarchical numbering preceding the text. In addition to the greater reliability attributed to this approach, different house style specifications for heading text on the one hand and heading numbering on the other made this necessary. But as a result of this, our headings are "Numbered items" instead of "Headings" in terms of reference type. Consequently, no elements which can be referenced are listed in the dialog box if the "Heading" reference type is preset or selected manually by the user. A user who now wants to set a cross-reference to something he or she naturally considers a “heading” may easily become frustrated by this. Hence, for sake of usability, the above-mentioned default settings which can be implemented quite simply via the dialog object:

```
With Dialogs(wdDialogInsertCrossReference)
    .ReferenceType = "Numbered item"
    .InsertAsHyperlink = True
End With
```

However, the cross-reference dialog box is displayed as modal in this way, i.e. it must be closed before the user can continue working in the Word document. If a user wants to insert more than one cross-reference at more than one place in the document, he or she would have to open and close the dialog box several times - which in turn leads to frustration on the part of the experienced users of my target group who prefer to insert many cross-references in one go.

As an alternative to using the dialog object, the cross-reference dialog box can also be opened using the CommandBar object and the FindControl method, and will then be displayed as modeless. However, this approach does not allow the desired presets to be assigned.

For me, the solution to this dilemma was, similar as suggested by Yorik above, a combination of both approaches: First, the dialog box is called via the dialog object as above, together with the desired presets, but is closed again immediately using the Show method (TimeOut). The dialog box is then reopened as a CommandBar object using the FindControl method. The previously assigned presets are simply retained by Word as the last used settings.

```
With Dialogs(wdDialogInsertCrossReference)
    .ReferenceType = "Numbered item"
    .InsertAsHyperlink = True
    .Show (1)
End With

Application.CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=775).Execute
```

The downside of this solution is that the dialog box that opens, closes and reopens seems to flicker for the user. I can live with that, but it also means that this is not an optimal solution, but merely a workaround that works for my problem and is acceptable to me. ***TGR***